# Using streamreader in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, while-loop, streamreader, void

How do you guys actually use the `StreamReader` to read the .txt file and match with two of my Combobox's text such as SGD - Singapore Dollar and USD - US Dollar so that it writes on the label that shows the number of 1.26?

Exchange.txt:

> SGD - Singapore Dollar || USD - US Dollar = 1.26

Here's the code:

```
private void GetExchangeRate()
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Exchange.txt"))
    {
        string[] store = new string[100];
        int index = 0;
        string line;

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            store[index] = line;
            index++;
            lblexchange.Text = sr.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

private void tocountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnupdate.Enabled = true;
    txtvalue.Enabled = true;
    GetExchangeRate();
}
```

In the end, the label did not show the value of 1.26. I don't know what's wrong with it. I need help

Comment: Any reason why you are calling this inside the while loop `lblexchange.Text = sr.ReadLine();`

Comment: Break down your question into smaller problems. Are you having trouble reading from the file, or are you having difficulties comparing two strings? Currently it seems that you're asking us to write your code.

Comment: difficulties comparing two strings that is equal to 1.26

Comment: @KRAZE actually i gt no idea what im coding..

Comment: by the way i need the label to have 1.26 in the end after reading and taking the value of 1.26 from the .txt file

Comment: i wish i can post pictures to show you guys...

Comment: You can post your code and what you want to do and what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
private void GetExchangeRate()
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Exchange.txt");

    foreach (var line in lines) { 
        //Suppose your line contains 'Singapore' and you want to do somthing if line contains the singapore then you should do as 
         if(line.Contains("Singapore"))
          {
               lblDisplay.Text = "Singapore"
          }
       //Do your functionality that is which line to display depending upon country
       // You can match the line and display them according to your need  
    }
 }
```

Comment: for example in the foreach loop? im sorry because i dont really know how to use this..

Comment: sorry to ask again but its the last time... what if i want to display a decimal?

Comment: you can display anything you want just you have to adjust your condition according to it

Comment: oh yeah one more thing, how do you code it if you want another conversion like Singapore dollars to Malaysian ringgit?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use

```
File.ReadAllLines("Exchange.txt")
```

It will return you all lines in an array of string.

Comment: where should i put it?

Comment: string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Exchange.txt");
 foreach (var line in lines)
 {
     // do whatever you want to do with each line
 }

Comment: i dont really know what to do inside the foreach loop. Im sorry if this is frustrating